# How to prevent Xcode 4 for making the last closed window the main project window?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, project

Some time ago I adapted my Xcode workflow using the "tab-approach" as described by Brian Webster on his [blog](http://brian-webster.tumblr.com/post/22060296528/how-to-make-xcode-4s-ui-work-for-you-maybe). It takes some time to set it up but I really enjoy working like that.

However, sometimes I open a file by double clicking it in the project manager, opening it into a new window. Not really a problem I thought, but it seems that the last window you close in a project will become the main project window, forgetting my tab-based workflow when I reopen the project. It happens a lot that I accidentally close the main window first, and then see that I still had a window open on another screen.

I reached the point that I am fed up reconfiguring it all the time, creating all these tabs again.

Does anyone know how to solve this - is there for example a way I can save the current configuration of tabs and their opened files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve this was by going to Xcode>Preferences>General and changing Double Click Navigation drop down to Uses separate tab.  I know this is not the ideal solution, but it works for me.

Comment: I hadn't seen that setting before. Thanks, this is an adequate solution for me as well.